# Is (function expression) {Using grouping operator to surround a function expression} actually valid?

Tags: javascript

Based on the official [ECMA-262 edition 5.1 June 2011 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

[The grammar summary defines that a grouping operator(parentheses) may only contain an expression](http://es5.github.com/#A.3):

```
PrimaryExpression :

this
Identifier
Literal
ArrayLiteral
ObjectLiteral
( Expression )
```

And an expression can only be an Assignmentexpression(or a sequence of those)(scroll to the end of [section A.3](http://es5.github.com/#A.3))

```
Expression :

AssignmentExpression
Expression , AssignmentExpression
```

So according to the ECMA-262 edition 5.1 the following should be incorrect: `(FunctionExpression)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging I figured out it is actually valid. Here is the complete derivation(to retrace it go to the end of [section A.3](http://es5.github.com/#A.3) and follow the derivations upwards starting from `Expression`:

```
Expression -> AssignmentExpression -> ConditionalExpression ->
LogicalORExpression -> LogicalANDExpression -> 
BitwiseORExpression -> BitwiseXORExpression -> 
BitwiseANDExpression -> EqualityExpression -> 
RelationalExpression -> ShiftExpression -> AdditiveExpression -> 
MultiplicativeExpression -> UnaryExpression -> 
PostfixExpression -> LeftHandSideExpression -> NewExpression -> 
MemberExpression -> FunctionExpression
```

Comment: +1, makes sense--I started down the path to see if it could be reached another way, but then ate lunch instead. (Not sure you need to include each of the expression types, though; aren't the OR/AND/etc. equivalent?)

Comment: @Dave Regarding the expressions apparently they are not equivalent, for example from `ConditionalExpression` you can only derive `LogicalORExpression`